# Dynamic URL Issue with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to fetch json files for different users according to their User_ID, but currently this code is showing empty recyclerview

**Retrofit File**

```
public void loadJSONClaim() {
    Retrofit retrofitclaim = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://ec2-54-191-118-200.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterfaceClaim requestclaim = retrofitclaim.create(RequestInterfaceClaim.class);
String User_ID = 5;
    Call<JSONResponseClaim> call = requestclaim.getJSONClaim(User_ID);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponseClaim>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponseClaim> call, Response<JSONResponseClaim> responseclaim) {

            JSONResponseClaim jsonResponseClaim = responseclaim.body();
            dataclaim = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponseClaim.getAndroidClaim()));
            adapterclaim = new DataAdapterClaim(dataclaim);
        }
```

**RequestInterFaceClaim**

```
public interface RequestInterfaceClaim {

    @GET("claim.php") // we want to access claim.php?User_ID=5
    Call<JSONResponseClaim> getJSONClaim(@Query("User_ID") String User_ID);
}
```

Comment: `dataclaim` empty too ?

Comment: yes, whole adapter is empty

Comment: Add `JSONResponseClaim` to post.

Comment: post `claim.php` code please